# wordpress frontend editor to add extra css to website

Tags: php, plugin-development

i need to create a plugin that allows me to select any button or any part of the website and  add extra css to it ,i have manages to consumer rest api within wp ,add menus and submit forms but i have no idea how to accomplish this task ,i would appreciate any suggestion 
thanks

Comment: Why can't you just add CSS using the Additional CSS section of the customiser?

Comment: i don't want to add css classes,insted i need to add exta css  to specific html button/ a tags and so on

Comment: Why can’t you do that with regular CSS?

Comment: sorry my bad i didn't explain the issue well , i don't need to add classes to css files but i need to add specfic css classes to tags regardless of their exsitance in a css file , so the task is to change the the html generated by wp and to trigger that i need to click on an item (button,rating....) and a css class to it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth studying how other plugins work, for example: Visual Composer.

The logic that came into my head, is to pick the element selector clicked with jQuery, and work on it. Read this that may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706837/get-unique-selector-of-element-in-jquery

Following this logic, if each page element has the same class, it will be easier to work with

Comment: thanks Gabriel, studied various plugins,they only allow users to edit elements created with the same  plugin so visual  composer for instance won't regognize elements created with beaver

Comment: @JawharJarrar
I found this plugin
https://gist.github.com/saarmstrong/5e8d2ac45dfd76a2574f

In thesis this:

$ ("*"). click (function () {
    var path = $ ('this) .getPath ();
    console.log (path);
});

It should return something like:
// html> body> div # bar> ul # abc.def.ghi> li # foo "

Ai you just work css ...

But I did not test, if it works, let me know! I think it can help with my projects too.